# What would be day to day life like, for people during a renaissance like period in a world I'm building

Tags: technology, culture, science-in-society, history, daily-life

Like I said, what would people eat, what would they drink, how'd they spend their time. I realise this isn't really a hypothetical question, rather a question that requires some information from an expert in the period.
I am making a Netherlands-like country and a book recommendation about life during that time and in that location would be terrific.

Comment: This question is better suited for history.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's also hugely broad - a three century period covering which country? Which region, and profession? There are regions in our world where it's not even happened yet, other regions where it technically can't happen. You'd need to read about [history.se]'s posting requirements before asking there too. Good luck.

Comment: This would depend hugely on what you want the world to be. Maybe people spend most of their day training for war, maybe they spend it meditating on the nature of art. Maybe they are fighting over the nature of art. Or numerous other possibilities. Even if you base the world on historical "typical days" that's a huge variety to choose from when you take different eras, different strata of society and different locations. You can also mix and match, there, if needed.

Comment: Ian Mortimer, *The Time-Traveller's Guide to Elizabethan England*, 2008, ISBN 0224079948. And specifically for the Low Countries, any good book about Pieter Brueghel the Elder's life and work would be of great help.